# MAMP cannot connect to localhost

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, mamp

Big picture: trying to update a 5 year old WordPress site without losing all the calendar plug-in posts.

Macro: downloaded MAMP to setup a local test site. Cannot get past index page to connect to database.

What works:

- Index page shows my test sites (I have three versions of wordpress
  Installed (3.0.5 / 3.9.1.1 / 4.4.2), so I can incrementally test and
  upgrade)
- I can login to phpMyAdmin no problem
- I exported the old database to a .sql file, then imported it up to the new Local database, it showed up fine, but tells me "Your PHP MySQL library version 5.1.73 differs from your MySQL server version 5.5.48"
- The wp-config.php usernames and passwords all match to the database

After many searches and most of the day trying different things, I am stumped. Obviously, I am a complete noob to MySQL and PHP.

What I have tried:

- Changing port to 90 instead of 80
- Changing the user to 'root' and 'admin'
- Changing from define('DB_HOST', 'localhost’); to define('DB_HOST', '86.42.246.7:80’); and define('DB_HOST', '86.42.246.7:90’);

Notes:

- I initially edited the files with textedit, but noticed it was changing single quotes to leave syntax errors - now I'm using Dreamweaver.
- Is it possible I could just import each table one at a time into a newly created database?

   Please help me out!

EDIT
I changed the database password, but I got this error message
"phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server."

Comment: DId you set any password of your phpMyAdmin?

Comment: User should be 'root'
Pass ''
host should be 'localhost'

Comment: Can you please post you connection string you have set?

Comment: Where do I find the connection string Muhammad Umar?

Comment: You should have database connection string in your php code. You must have to modify that connection string......

Comment: Is that in wp-config.php?

Comment: May be. It depends. I can't tell you without having a look on your files......

Comment: Maybe someone who is experienced with wordpress can tell you without looking your files.....

Comment: could I use a command line:

SET PASSWORD FOR 'localhost' = PASSWORD(‘password’);

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

Comment: you can see connection string in wp-config.php.......

Comment: Send me your wp-config.php code i can modify it for you

Comment: // ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'drivingmenuts');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'drivingmenuts');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'Sw0rdf1sh');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');

Comment: Paul come in inbox.......

Comment: What is your phpMyAdmin Password?

Comment: Sw0rdf1sh is the phpMyAdmin password. Inbox just brings me back to this page, sorry for all the comments

Comment: Hey Paul, Do you have Teamviewer installed in your computer so that I can check that whats the problem because you are mixing up the things. Did yo set any password after setting phpMyAdmin? Sw0rdf1sh is the password of your online server not local server

Comment: I don't have teamviewer. How about email?